# Short story dystopia about a state that enforces healthy living

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia

I am looking for a short story I read some time in the 90ies in a German anthology. The story itself could be from the seventies, eighties or nineties. As far as I remember the author was an Italian.

The story was a dystopia about a society on Earth in a not to distant future where the state enforces healthy living. I don't remember many of the details. One point of the story I remember was a couple defying the state by having a picnic with unhealthy food outside the city.

Comment: Not much of a clue to work with: can't you remember anything more? Present-day or future? Who was/were the protagonist(s)? What was the overall tone of the story? Did you remember if it ended well? Tell us more to help us help. That said, did you already check Dino Buzzati? That might be your starting point if your author was an Italian and active up to the Seventies.

Comment: It's not a short story, nor is the author Italian, but the picnic aspect:  sneaking out of the city to eat forbidden, tasty food, sounds like *Wyst: Alastor 1716* by Jack Vance.

Comment: @Buzz thanks for the comment. That's not what I'm looking for, though. I am certain this was a short-story. It was also playing on Earth in a "not to distant future"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've read it, it is a story by [Lino Aldani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lino_Aldani). [Here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lino_Aldani) the link to the Wikipedia page in German.
The Italian title is "Trentasette Centigradi" ("Thirty-seven degrees", in German "Siebenunddreißig Grad").

It is based on the premise that it would make more sense for people to pay doctors when they're healthy, rather than sick.

So, all people had to pay a very expensive insurance as long as they were healthy, in order to receive medical care in case of sickness (and of course they didn't have to pay as long as they were sick).
Since doctor were paid as long as their patients were healthy, the insurance required people to live a healthy life, also with the help of insurance agents whose task was to avoid people to do anything that could endanger their health. 
There were some people who decided not to pay the insurance: because of its cost, they were much wealthier than the average citizen, but in case of illness they had no right to receive medications or medical care.

The story itself is about a man who decided to stop paying such insurance, in order to be finally free to do unhealthy things without insurance wards to prevent him (such as the pic-nic mentioned by the OP).

Comment: It is interesting that a German wrote this: One could see nazi German instituting a very invasive national health program -- indeed, this had already started. A natural extension of, for example, their encouragement of high number of births. Other examples were anti-tobacco sentiment and even the T-4 program (which was more horrifying than most science fiction stories).